# Customized infopath form

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I have a SharePoint 2010 form library and a want the users to submit data in 2 different times, but the second time that the user edit the form I want the the data that he previously insert can not be deleted or changed (read only type). How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can created a hidden checkbox field `Submitted` and check it when the user submits the data. If the field is checked, that section should be read only.